# Select only one row in mat-table and if select other one then unselect first one

Tags: css, typescript, angular-material, angular5, mat-table

I want to implement table with only one row selection. Now i have multiple selection.

I tried coupe ways to do this and i stayed by this one.

Graphic example:
[image: Graphic example]

*component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { UsersReadRepository } from '../../../../core/services';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { User } from 'domain-models';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Subscribable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';

@Component({
    selector: 'choose-supervisior',
    templateUrl: './chooseSupervisior.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./chooseSupervisior.component.scss']
})

export class ChooseSupervisiorComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    selectedRow: User;
    isLoading = true;
    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<User> = new MatTableDataSource();
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'surname', 'phone'];
    subscription$ : Subscription;

    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ChooseSupervisiorComponent>, private userReadRepository: UsersReadRepository) {
    }
    onCloseDialog(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close(this.selectedRow);
      }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription$ = this.userReadRepository.getSupervisiorUsers()
        .subscribe(
            data => 
            {
                this.isLoading = false,
                this.dataSource.data = data;
            }
        )
    }
    highlight(highlighted: boolean) {
        highlighted = !highlighted;
      }

    getSupervisiorRecordFromTable(user: User){
        this.selectedRow = user;
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription$.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

*component.html*

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>{{'insideChats.chooseSupervisiorHeader' | translate}}</h2>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.name}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="surname">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Surname </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.surname}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Phone </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.phone}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" 
        (click)="getSupervisiorRecordFromTable(row)"
        [ngClass]="{hovered: row.hovered, highlighted: row.highlighted}" (click)="row.highlighted = !row.highlighted" (mouseover)="row.hovered = true" (mouseout)="row.hovered = false"></mat-row >
    </mat-table>
    <mat-card class="loading-spinner" *ngIf="isLoading">
  <mat-progress-spinner 
    color="primary" 
    mode="indeterminate">
  </mat-progress-spinner>
</mat-card>
</div>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-dialog-close (click)="onCloseDialog()" mat-icon-button color="warn">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
        <span class="buttons-spacer"></span>
    <button mat-button class="choose-button">{{'insideChats.chooseSupervisiorStartChat' | translate}}</button>
</div>
```

*component.scss*

```
.loading-spinner{
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;
}

  .buttons-spacer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }

  .mat-dialog-actions {
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }

  .basic-container {
    padding: 5px;
  }

  .mat-row.hovered {
    background: #eee;
  }

  .mat-row.highlighted {
    background: #999;
  }

  mat-cell.mat-cell, mat-header-cell.mat-header-cell {
    overflow: visible; 
  }
```

How to implement row selection with unsellecting the last one clicked selection and then this same with other clicking.

The point is just always available select only one row.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using a `SelectionModel` with multi-selection disabled will make things easier. See the example: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#selection.

Here's a modified version of the example on Stackblitz without the checkboxes and using single selection and some of your table's functionality: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2yv8hk?file=app/table-selection-example.html.

In particular:

TS

```
export class TableSelectionExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  selection = new SelectionModel<PeriodicElement>(false, []);
}
```

HTML

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" 
  (click)="selection.toggle(row)" 
  [ngClass]="{hovered: row.hovered, highlighted: selection.isSelected(row)}"
  (mouseover)="row.hovered = true" (mouseout)="row.hovered = false">
</mat-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to get the index of the row? (I don't really use angular) So you save the index when clicking the row in data as 'pastIndex', define a method for when you click the row, pseudocodeish:

```
rowClick (index) {
  if (this.pastIndex is defined) {
      data[this.pastIndex].highlighted = false
  }
  this.pastIndex = index
  data[index].highlighted = true
}
```

If not, this is not ideal, but you could traverse your whole data and make everything false and then just make the one you need true

```
rowClick (index) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i].highlighted = false
  }
  data[index].highlighted = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Perfect example of Single and Multiple Checkbox selection with Mat Table
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-selection

Mat table Selection as a propert`enter code here`y `selection.selected` which contains all the selected

Angular Official Documentation
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#selection

```
selectHandler(row: PeriodicElement) {
    if (this.displayType == SelectType.single) {
    /* Single checkbox Selection*/
    if (!this.selection.isSelected(row)) {
        this.selection.clear();
    }
    }
/* Multiple checkbox Selection*/
    this.selection.toggle(row);
  }
```